# Html Parser Tag class Access

Tags: java, javascript, html, html-parsing

I want to access a class in html code as

```
<id="main" class="cop">
<div class="body">
  <table class="" summary="">
     <colgroup class="game_title">//1
 <col class="thumb">
 <col class="game_title">//2
 </colgroup>

<tbody class="">
     <tr class="game">
 <td class="thumb">
 <a rel="nofollow" href=""><img src="" alt="Grudger thumbnail"></a>
 </td>
 <td class="game_title">//3

 **<div class=**"game_title"**><a href="">Grudger</a></div>//I want to access this class only**
```

I used code as

```
Element INFORM = source.getElementById("main").getAllElementByclass("game_title");
```

for accessing class `game_title` having element Gruger
but this code not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function($){
      $result = $(#main .game_title).html();
   });

</script>
```

Comment: please explain me in html jericho parser other script i have not to used

Answer (score 0):

Try JQuery class [selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

or with JavaScript try document.getElementsByClassName('game_title')